# Truncate with zeros and round BigInt

Tags: javascript, bigint

I have a BigInt 123456789n. I want to truncate it with two zeros to 123456700n. But I don't think that is good enough - I want the last remaining digit to be rounded by the last truncated number. So the result should be 123456800n.

Examples:

```
1100n should be 1100n
1149n should be 1100n
1150n should be 1200n
1199n should be 1200n
```

A solution with a configurable amount of zeros would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?

```js
const f = (x,y) => ((x / y) * y) + (x%y >= 5n*(y/10n) ? y : 0n);
const y = 100n; // amount of padding, 100 = 2 last digits will become 0, 1000 = 3 last, etc. 
console.log(f(1100n, y)); // 1100n
console.log(f(1149n, y)); // 1100n
console.log(f(1150n, y)); // 1200n
console.log(f(1199n, y)); // 1200n
console.log(f(1200n, y)); // 1200n
console.log(f(11499n, 1000n)); // 11000n
console.log(f(11500n, 1000n)); // 12000n
console.log(f(123456789n, y)); // 123456800n
```

```html
<!-- See browser console for output -->
```

The `(x / y) * y` will remove the last two digits when `y = 100` from the number `x`.
Eg:

```
(x/y) = 1149n / 100n = 11n 
(x/y) * y = 11n * 100n = 1100n
```

Now it's just a matter of deciding whether to add `y` to the above result (ie: round it up) or leave it as is (round down). There is probably a more mathematical way of doing this, but one way could be to use a ternary.

For example, with `1149`, the last digits which we want to become 0 are `49`, this can be checked to see if it is greater than or equal to 50, and if it is, add `y`. If it is less than 50, add 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that involves far too many strings. Something less ugly would be welcome.

```js
function truncateAndRound(input) {
  let str = input.toString();
  if (str.length < 2) {
    str = str.padStart(2, '0');
  }

  let num = BigInt(str) / 100n;
  const fraction = BigInt(str.slice(str.length - 2, str.length));

  if (fraction >= 50n) {
    num += 1n;
  }
  str = num.toString();

  return str + '00';
}

console.log(truncateAndRound(1100n));
console.log(truncateAndRound(1149n));
console.log(truncateAndRound(1150n));
console.log(truncateAndRound(1199n));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, strings - your approach is the only option. Everything you can do is to make, to improve your function to be more elegant. But that's all.